# How to setup a software project so that different cross compile targets for the project map to diff. TFS branches of a single project

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

IDE= Visual Studio 2017 Community 
How can I setup a software project so that different cross compile targets for the project map to diff. TFS branches of a single project.
Another related query how to map debug and release versions for one compile target, taking into account previous query above, in VS hosted TFS online.

Comment: What do you mean cross compile targets? Can you provide the sample to explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean configuration and platform, you don’t need to do it, also it is based on the configuration and platform you selected in Visual Studio, you just need to change the configuration and platform before build the project.

Refer to these steps to configure configuration and platform for each project.

1. Right click solution > Configuration Manager
2. Choose configuration and platform for solution
3. Choose configuration and platform for projects
4. Change configuration and platform for solution in Visual Studio

[image]

5. Build the solution or just the project